# Commuting to work for the first time, what do I need to bring?

Tags: safety, commuter, fixed-gear

I've never biked to work, but am going to start next week. It's only about 15 miles round trip. I'm using a single speed bike, but it should be fine because I've gone on farther trips.

Besides a change of clothes, what are the essential items that I need to bring with me? Safety is important so besides a helmet, what safety equipment do I need to have/use?

Any tips would also be helpful because I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Allocate enough time, bring lights and locks, pick a good route. Extra clothes may not be necessary depending on weather and riding speed and required work attire (7.5 miles each way seems too short to want to use padded bike shorts).

Comment: Wash kit, flannel, deodorant.

Comment: Spare tube and tools to replace it.

Comment: Lights (and usb cable to recharge)

Comment: @batman 1km is enough to justify padded shorts! Lol.

Comment: A tube repair kit, in case you fail to remove the cause of your first puncture.

Comment: You don't *need* a helmet.

Comment: @vclaw  depends on the location - OP never said where in the world they are.

Comment: I'm surprised noones mentioned water, and to allow more than enough time for the trip.   I like 10 minutes at work to cool down before commencing work.